# How to check parameter is not null value sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to check parameter has null or not in stored procedure

e.g

```
select * from tb_name where name=@name
```

i need to check if @name has values or null means.how to do it.thanks...

Comment: You can do something like `select * from tb_name where @name IS NULL OR name=@name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select * from tb_name where name=@name and @name is not null
```

Actually, the extra check is unnecessary, because `NULL` will fail any comparison.  Sometimes, `NULL` is used to mean "get all of them".  In that case, you want:

```
select * from tb_name where name=@name or @name is null
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want results where Name is not null **and** equal to `@name` Try:

```
select * from tb_name where name=@name AND @name IS NOT NULL
```

If you want results where Name is null **Or** equal to `@name` Try:

```
select * from tb_name where name=@name OR @name IS NULL
```

Where you looking for one of those?

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from tb_name 
where ((@name  is null) or ([name] = @name))
```